# Laravel Where Clause To Search In Columns Which Are Not In The Database

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent, attributes

I have a table `organisations` with a number of columns, namely `id`, `name`, `created_at` and `updated_at`.

In my `Organisation` model, I added a custom attribute by adding the following code in the model:

```
// Add custom attributes
    protected $appends = [
        'device_count',
    ];
```

and:

```
public function getDeviceCountAttribute()
    {
        // Count organisation's devices
        $device_count = Device::where('organisation_id', '=', $this->id)->count();
        return $device_count;
    }
```

In my controller, I am trying to search (using the `where` clause) by the `device_count` attribute, but I'm getting an error since this is not a real column in my database table.

- This is how I'm searching:

```
$organisations = Organisation::query();
$organisations = $organisations->where('device_count', '=', 0);
$organisations = $organisations->get();
```

- This is the error:

```
[2020-10-14 12:29:27] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'device_count' in 'field list'...
```

Is there an alternative to the `where` clause in order to search by `device_count` please?

Answer (score 3):

You can't query against attributes like that, they only exist on the model and do not exist in the database. However, you don't need to create a getter for that.

Laravel has a `withCount()` method you can use instead of that attribute - which is the correct approach of obtaining relational counts.

So a query with that attribute would look like

```php
$organisations = Organisation::withCount('devices')->get();
```

The resulting models will now have a `device_count` attribute on them, that you can use in your views.

---

Then in your query, to filter those records that has at least a certain relational count, you can do

```php
$organisations = Organisation::has('devices', '=', 0)->get();
```

Since you're looking for those that *do not* have any relation, you can replace it with `doesntHave()`.  The above snippet is included to show how you can query against a specific set of relational counts.

To query only those that don't have any related devices, simply do

```php
$organisations = Organisation::doesntHave('devices')->get();
```

This assumes that you have defined a `devices` relation on your `Organisation` class.

```php
public function devices() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Device::class); // Or App\Device::class if your models are not in the Models namespace/directory
}
```

The approaches above are the Laravel-way of doing it - and you should therefor remove your `getDeviceCountAttribute()` method and the corresponding `device_count` from `$appends`.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you want to get those `Organisations` which `doesnot` have any `devices`

For that, you need to use `doesntHave` method.

Make a relationship in the **Organisation** model.

```
public function devices() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Device','organisation_id','id');
}
```

Now call the mothed in controller/

```
$organisations = Organisation::doesntHave('devices')->get();
```

it will return you those `organisations` which `devices` are not exists.